# erasing 0's from left to right in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a column in a mysql database table like:

```
   code
  0001109A
  00002443BD
  .....
  1233FGV
  0PEI223334
```

i.e. at some rows the code field could have several 0 from left to right and if I find a field like that I need to extract all the 0s. For example, for 00002443BD I need to return  2443BD, for 0PEI223334 I need to return PEI223334, and so on. The number of 0s is not known. Any suggestions?

Comment: `trim(leading '0' from code)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are describing a simple `TRIM()` operation.  Other languages and contexts may call this `strip()`.  In context of what you asked:

```
SELECT TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM `code`) FROM your_table
```

For completeness, note that:

- The default is to trim whitespace from either end, which is the same as `BOTH`:

  ```
  SELECT TRIM('    HI    ')              --> 'HI'
  SELECT TRIM(BOTH FROM '    HI    ')    --> 'HI'
  ```
- There's `TRAILING` to trim from the end of the string

  ```
  SELECT TRIM(TRAILING FROM '    HI    ')    --> '    HI'
  ```

Resources:

- [Official Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_trim)  (Check out `TRIM`, and perhaps `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` if you only need to remove spaces.)
- [Handy run-through](https://techjourney.net/remove-or-trim-first-or-last-few-characters-in-mysql-database-with-sql/)